# Flaw in induction proof that the Fibonacci sequence is bounded by $(5/3)^n$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers

> The Fibonacci sequence is defined by $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1$ and for all $n \ge 2, a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}$. Thus the sequence begins
>
> $$1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,...$$
>
> Prove that for all $n \ge 1, a_n < (5/3)^n$

Here is what I tried. But I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Base case, $n = 1$:
$$a_1 = 1 > \frac{5}{3}$$

Inductive step:
Assume that $a_n < (\frac{5}{3})^n$ for all $1 \le k \le n$ as the inductive hypothesis.

$$a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1}$$

$$a_{n+1} < \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^n + \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{n-1}$$

$$a_{n+1} < \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{n-1} \cdot \left(\frac{5}{3}+1\right)$$

$$a_{n+1} < \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{n-1} \cdot \left(\frac{8}{3}\right)$$

$$\left(\frac{8}{3}\right) < \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{25}{9}$$

$$a_{n+1} < \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{n-1} \cdot \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^2$$

$$a_{n+1} < \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{n+1}$$

Comment: Apart from a typo in the base case ($1<\frac53$), the lack of considering the second base case $a_2<(\frac{5}{3})^2$ and the lack of interpunction (or at least connectives such as $\iff$, here more properly only $\implies$ in most cases) between the proof lines - your proof is fine.

Comment: Well, you typo'ed $\left(\frac52\right)^2$ where it should be $\frac53$. But that doesn't make it incorrect in principle.

Answer (score 2):

A couple typos, and suggestion to consider; but substantively, there is very little "wrong" with your proof. You did the hardest part, and the proof is fine (with typos corrected!)

- As pointed out in the comments, you want the direction of the inequality for the base case $a_1$ reversed. (Typo?).
- With this particular proof, I'd suggest also considering the second
  base case: establishing: $$a_2 = 1 \lt \left(\frac 53\right)^2.$$
- What I suspect is another typo, you typed $\left(\frac 52\right)^2$
  but want $\left(\frac 53\right)^2$ in the third from the last line.
- Finally, and more importantly, [here's the suggestion I am asking you
  to consider]: don't be afraid to use more *words* in a proof: Explain
  what you are doing. You need to make clear the relationships between
  your lines of reasoning: Line (i) $\iff$ Line (j)? Or does one given
  inequality *imply* the subsequent inequality? If so, indicate so, in
  words or in symbols: e.g., using: "$\implies.$"